# How can we explain love and hatred in spiritual parlance, particularly with reference to Advait Darshan?

Tags: philosophy, advaita, upanishads, spirituality, love

For a seeker to appreciate and comprehend certain character traits are of utmost importance.

Shall feel blessed if some blessed one could explain the philosophy of love and hatred in spiritual parlance keeping in mind the Advait Darshan.

Answer (score 1):

The following are excerpts from the teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

1. ***On dvaita and advaita***

> An educated visitor asked Bhagavan about dvaita and advaita.
>
> M.: Identification with the body is dvaita. Non-identification is
>   advaita.

2. On Self and ego

> D.: I understand theoretically. But they are still there.
>
> M.: Yes. It is like a cinema-show. There is the light on the screen
>   and the shadows flitting across impress the audience as the enactment
>   of some piece. Similarly also will it be, if in the same play an
>   audience also is shown. The seer, the seen, will then only be the
>   screen.
>
> Apply it to yourself. You are the screen, the *Self has created the
>   ego, **the ego has its accretions of thoughts** which are displayed as the
>   world, the trees, plants, etc., of which you are asking.*
>
> **In reality, all these are nothing but the Self.**
>
> If you see the Self, the same will be found to be all, everywhere and
>   always. Nothing but the Self exists.

---

This is about advaita in brief.

So everything boils downs to the false identification of one's SELF to one's body.  Then rises the EGO or "I".

Our ***emotions*** like LOVE or HATRED or JEALOUSY or HAPPINESS or SEXUAL IMPULSE and so on, are arising because we are identifying ourselves with our bodies.

Comment: Such a convincing and revealing answer! Feel blessed  . This reply is with a purpose to convey. Only recently I have joined this community. For long I have been aspiring to find a forum exactly of a kind like present one. I am not at all an E-savvy, rather a complete beginner. Don't know how to handle and deal with such community. As such seek unconditional apologies for committing wrongs. Since long l have been comming across super natural experience s . Weeklong experience say -meeting with this community is one of them.

Comment: Let me continue, wrongly disrupted. During past few days I kept myself busy in finding answers to my long desired and outstanding  issues all related to path of upgradation, fortunately have been helped alot. Wrt my present question I had a great wish to find reply from a blessed and evolved soul. That exactly did happen  - I don't know how. I have reason to say this is one another instance of meeting blessed experience. I am yet to be familiarised with the culture of this community as such I seek unconditional apology  once again from those concerned. With Regards, Hare Krishna

Answer (score 0):

I think the Bhagavad Gita explains this very succinctly:

2.62:

> ध्यायतो विषयान्पुंसः सङ्गस्तेषूपजायते । सङ्गात्सञ्जायते कामः कामात्क्रोधोऽभिजायते ॥
> When a person keeps thinking about an entity (both animate (person) and inanimate), he gets attached to it. From attachment comes desire (to possess the entity), from desire comes anger/hatred (due to not being able to possess the entity).